# How to add some text in pptk viewer window?

Tags: python, text, point-cloud-library, pptk

I'd like to add some text in top of pptk viewer window. Is it possible?

I think it should be, but I didn't find anything from the documentation.

This works:

```
import pptk
v = pptk.viewer(pptk.rand(100, 3))
v.set(point_size=0.005)
```

But I'd like to have something like:

```
import pptk
v = pptk.viewer(pptk.rand(100, 3), title='Random points')
v.set(point_size=0.005)
```